# Indirect questions and the passive subjunctive

Tags: classical-latin, english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, syntax, indirect-question

How would you translate: "He asked if the the city had been captured?"

> Quaerit num civitatem captum esse?

Here I am using an accusative (captum) plus infinitive (esse).

Am I right?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As an indirect question in subjunctive: "Quaerit an/utrum civitas capta sit."

Comment: You are right !

Comment: Note that this means "he asks whether the city is captured".

Comment: I don't think so: "capta sit" is past perfect passive subjunctive.

Comment: Then what is  perfect passive subjunctive?

Comment: "Perfect" is short for "past perfect". "Quaerit utrum civitas capiatur" is in present subjective passive: "He/she asks whether the city *is* captured". On the other hand, "Quaerit utrum civitas capta sit" is in past perfect subjunctive passive, and it means "He/she asks whether the city *has been* captured". (Note that "an" and "utrum" are somewhat equivalent for the purpose of making indirect questions.)

Comment: All right, pluperfect, then. How would you translate *quaesivit utrum civitas capta esset*?

Comment: "... *had been* captured".

Comment: Hmm I see. I'm not entirely sure I agree with the options for *capta est* and your terminology, but I'll give these translations some more thought. At any rate, would you say your Latin matches the translation desired by Lawrence?

Answer (score 1):

An indirect question always uses subjunctive (also called conjunctive) in Latin.
You just write the question as if it were a normal question, and then change indicative to subjunctive.

An accusative with infinitive cannot be used for indirect questions.
Unless the question contains a question word (*quis*, *quando*, or similar), an indirect question is often introduced with *an* or *utrum*.

The translation suggested by NVaughan is great.